# Why can't sodium butyrate be delivered orally in humans and other mammals?

Tags: pharmacology, pharmacodynamics, pharmacokinetics

I think I know why -- **bioavailability** problems but since I have no firm evidence to support this theory I thought I would ask the biology stackexchange community for their input. I'd like some firm **bioavailability** data of **sodium butyrate** in mammals, preferably humans.

Comment: At least in humans butyrate tastes horrible I think.  that might be way it isn't taken orally.

Comment: @shigeta Na, I doubt it seeing how corticosteroids tend to taste terrible (which thing I know from personal experience as an asthmatic) and yet we have methods of getting around this problem such as putting them into capsules or telling the patients to just suck it up.

Comment: [Apparently it can](http://www.bodybio.com/storeproduct362.aspx)